# Returning data from c# controller to angular js controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

I am making some mistake in returning data from c# to angular controller,Here is my C# code

```
 public ActionResult FlightDisp()
        {          
            dynamic parsedJson = "";
            string myJsonResponse = "";
        
            try
            {
                const string URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                string token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";             
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "");
                Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.SendAsync(request);
                myJsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).ToString();
                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonResponse);
                parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return Json(  parsedJson );
        }
```

Whatever i get is parsed json is perfect but when i pass the parsedJson from c# to angular controller it becomes something like:

```
[
  [
    [
      [
        [
          []
        ],
        [
          [
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              []
            ],
            [
              [
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
              [
                [
                  [
                    []
                  ]
                ],
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
              [
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
              [
                [
                  []
                ],
                [
                  []
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
              [
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                [],
                []
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          []
        ],
        [
          [
            [
              [
                []
              ],
              [
                []
              ],
              [
                []
              ],
              [
                []
              ],
              [
                [
                  [
                    []
                  ],
                  [
                    []
                  ]
                ]
              ],
              [
                [
                  [
                    []
                  ],
                  [
                    [
                      [
                        []
                      ],
                      [
                        []
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
```

Its completely empty but parsedJson  has value :

```
{{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "ALNYC647",
        "chainCode": "AL",
        "dupeId": "501447323",
        "name": "Aloft Manhattan Downtown - Financial District",
        "rating": "4",
        "cityCode": "NYC",
        "latitude": 40.71041,
        "longitude": -74.00666,
        "hotelDistance": {
          "distance": 0.4,
          "distanceUnit": "KM"
        },
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "49 53 ANN STREET"
          ],
          "postalCode": "10038",
          "cityName": "NEW YORK",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "stateCode": "NY"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phone": "+1 212 513-0003",
          "fax": "+1 212 513-0004",
          "email": "info@aloftmanhattandowntown.com"
        },
        "description": {
          "lang": "en",
          "text": "Celebrate your style at Aloft Manhattan Downtown - Financial District, a hip new hotel where you'll be close to corporate headquarters, Wall Street and the World Trade Center. We offer easy-breezy access to Big Apple hotspots via nearby subway lines. Meet & mingle with friends at our w xyz(SM) bar, grab a sweet, savory or healthy snack from re:fuel by Aloft(SM), our 24/7 pantry or play in our re:mix(SM) lounge. Plus, you can always stay connected with free hotel-wide wired and wireless High Speed Internet Access! Breeze into one of our Aloft rooms, featuring our ultra-comfortable signature bed, walk-in shower, custom amenities by Bliss® Spa and more."
        },
        "amenities": [
          "SPA",
          "SERV_DOGS_ALWD",
          "ACC_TOILETS",
          "HANDRAIL_BTHRM",
          "24_HOUR_FRONT_DESK",
          "CAR_RENTAL",
          "EXPRESS_CHECK_IN",
          "LOUNGE",
          "ICE_MACHINES",
          "FLORIST",
          "TRAVEL_AGENCY",
          "CONCIERGE",
          "SAFE_DEP_BOX",
          "LAUNDRY_SVC",
          "ATM/CASH_MACHINE",
          "EXPRESS_CHECK_OUT",
          "WEDDING_SERVICES",
          "GYM",
          "RESTAURANT",
          "HI_INTERNET",
          "FREE_INTERNET",
          "WIRELESS_CONNECTIVITY",
          "ELEVATOR",
          "PETS_ALLOWED",
          "PHOTOCOPIER",
          "PRINTER",
          "BUSINESS_CENTER",
          "MEETING_FACILITIES",
          "INTERNET-HI_SPEED_IN_RM",
          "WI-FI_IN_ROOM",
          "NONSMOKING_RMS",
          "FREE_LOCAL_CALLS",
          "TEA/COFFEE_MK_FACILITIES",
          "ALARM_CLOCK",
          "AIR_CONDITIONING",
          "SAFE",
          "IRON/IRON_BOARD",
          "CRIBS_AVAILABLE",
          "TELEVISION",
          "HAIR_DRYER",
          "VOICEMAIL_IN_ROOM",
          "PHONE-DIR_DIAL",
          "CORDLESS_PHONE",
          "REFRIGERATOR",
          "OUTLET_ADAPTERS",
          "CABLE_TELEVISION",
          "FITNESS_CENTER"
        ]
      },
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "LBRB9R0B0X",
          "checkInDate": "2020-09-13",
          "checkOutDate": "2020-09-14",
          "rateCode": "S9R",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "SRS",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "room": {
            "type": "XMI",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
            "description": {
              "lang": "EN",
              "text": "Marriott Senior Discount, includes 62 years and older valid ID \nSleeps 2, Fast & free WiFi throughout the hotel\n, 1 Queen, 200sqft/18sqm-220sqft/20sqm, Wireles"
            }
          },
          "guests": {
            "adults": 1
          },
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "base": "127.00",
            "total": "149.25",
            "variations": {
              "average": {
                "base": "127.00"
              },
              "changes": [
                {
                  "startDate": "2020-09-13",
                  "endDate": "2020-09-14",
                  "base": "127.00"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "policies": {
            "paymentType": "guarantee",
            "cancellation": {
              "deadline": "2020-09-13T09:29:00+05:30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=ALNYC647"
    },
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "HXNYC432",
        "chainCode": "HX",
        "dupeId": "700051862",
        "name": "HAMPTON INN MANHATTAN-DOWNTOWN-FINANCIAL",
        "rating": "2",
        "cityCode": "NYC",
        "latitude": 40.70312,
        "longitude": -74.01228,
        "hotelDistance": {
          "distance": 1.3,
          "distanceUnit": "KM"
        },
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "32 PEARL ST"
          ],
          "postalCode": "10004",
          "cityName": "NEW YORK",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "stateCode": "NY"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phone": "1-212-480-3500",
          "fax": "1-212-480-3700"
        },
        "amenities": [
          "BUSINESS_CENTER",
          "ADAPTED_PHONES",
          "WIDE_ENTRANCE",
          "WIDE_CORRIDORS",
          "FIRST_AID_STAF",
          "INT_ROOM_ENTRY",
          "EMERG_LIGHTING",
          "FIRE_DETECTORS",
          "EXTINGUISHERS",
          "FIRE_SAFETY",
          "RESTRIC_RM_ACC",
          "SMOKE_DETECTOR",
          "SPRINKLERS",
          "LAUNDRY_SVC",
          "PARKING",
          "PETS_ALLOWED",
          "SAFE_DEP_BOX",
          "AIR_CONDITIONING",
          "HAIR_DRYER",
          "MOVIE_CHANNELS",
          "NONSMOKING_RMS",
          "PC_HOOKUP_INRM",
          "TELEVISION",
          "FITNESS_CENTER"
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "uri": "http://uat.multimediarepository.testing.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/9E95CFEC3B6F4C459EDC0F267159B799",
            "category": "EXTERIOR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "Y0IT2BLO9V",
          "checkInDate": "2020-09-13",
          "checkOutDate": "2020-09-14",
          "rateCode": "RAC",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "AAA",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "commission": {
            "percentage": "10.00"
          },
          "boardType": "BREAKFAST",
          "room": {
            "type": "C1Q",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "category": "ACCESSIBLE_ROOM",
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
            "description": {
              "lang": "EN",
              "text": "AAA RATE\n1 QUEEN ACCESSIBLE ROLL IN SHOWER NONSMOKING\nHDTV/WORK AREA"
            }
          },
          "guests": {
            "adults": 1
          },
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "base": "594.15",
            "total": "685.29",
            "variations": {
              "average": {
                "base": "594.15"
              },
              "changes": [
                {
                  "startDate": "2020-09-13",
                  "endDate": "2020-09-14",
                  "base": "594.15"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "policies": {
            "paymentType": "guarantee",
            "cancellation": {
              "deadline": "2020-09-10T09:30:00+05:30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=HXNYC432"
    },
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "BWNYC133",
        "chainCode": "BW",
        "dupeId": "700101379",
        "name": "Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel",
        "rating": "2",
        "cityCode": "NYC",
        "latitude": 40.7184,
        "longitude": -73.99518,
        "hotelDistance": {
          "distance": 1.0,
          "distanceUnit": "KM"
        },
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "231 GRAND STREET"
          ],
          "postalCode": "10013",
          "cityName": "NEW YORK CITY",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "stateCode": "NY"
        },
        "contact": {
          "phone": "+1 212 9251177",
          "fax": "+1 212 9255533",
          "email": "33133@hotel.bestwestern.com"
        },
        "description": {
          "lang": "en",
          "text": "Stay at this 100% non-smoking New York City, New York hotel located next to the subway and key local attractions such as Canal Street, Chinatown and Little Italy. Welcome to the Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel, where guests will find exceptional customer service and accommodations at an affordable rate. This New York City hotel features well-appointed guest rooms and suites, each offering cable satellite television with free HBO® and free wireless high-speed Internet access. Guests staying at this 100% non-smoking hotel will enjoy a complimentary hot breakfast buffet each morning before heading out to sightsee. Additional amenities include an exercise facility and a full-service business center. The Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel is ideally located less than one mile from many New York attractions including Chinatown, Little Italy, the Wall Street financial district and the World Trade Center Memorial. Hotel guests will enjoy an afternoon of shopping on 5th Avenue or visiting key sights such as Ellis Island, the Statue of Liberty, the Empire State Building and Times Square. Corporate travelers will appreciate being a half mile from the New York Stock Exchange, the Federal Reserve Bank, JP Morgan and American Express®. This New York hotel is also ideal for viewing several annual events including the Macy's Thanksgiving Day Parade®, the Chinese New Year and the Tribeca Film Festival. The friendly, helpful staff at the Best Western Bowery Hanbee Hotel is ready to ensure a fun-filled memorable stay in New York, New York. Make a reservation today and save! Enjoy your stay!"
        },
        "amenities": [
          "24_HOUR_FRONT_DESK",
          "GYM",
          "HI_INTERNET",
          "ELEVATOR",
          "ICE_MACHINES",
          "SPRINKLERS",
          "FIRE_DETECTORS",
          "FEMA_FIRE_SAFETY_COMPLIANT",
          "SMOKE_DETECTOR",
          "EMERG_LIGHTING",
          "HANDICAP_FAC",
          "BUSINESS_CENTER",
          "FREE_LOCAL_CALLS",
          "PHONE-DIR_DIAL",
          "INTERNET-HI_SPEED_IN_RM",
          "HAIR_DRYER",
          "AIR_CONDITIONING",
          "CABLE_TELEVISION",
          "VOICEMAIL_IN_ROOM",
          "SAFE",
          "WAKEUP_SERVICE",
          "ALARM_CLOCK",
          "TEA/COFFEE_MK_FACILITIES",
          "CRIBS_AVAILABLE"
        ],
        "media": [
          {
            "uri": "http://uat.multimediarepository.testing.amadeus.com/cmr/retrieve/hotel/A15115741A8747538ECDBB2AA76B7DE9",
            "category": "EXTERIOR"
          }
        ]
      },
      "available": true,
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": "MLX8YR77R7",
          "checkInDate": "2020-09-13",
          "checkOutDate": "2020-09-14",
          "rateCode": "SRS",
          "rateFamilyEstimated": {
            "code": "SRS",
            "type": "C"
          },
          "commission": {
            "percentage": "10"
          },
          "boardType": "BREAKFAST",
          "room": {
            "type": "A1Q",
            "typeEstimated": {
              "category": "ACCESSIBLE_ROOM",
              "beds": 1,
              "bedType": "QUEEN"
            },
            "description": {
              "lang": "EN",
              "text": "SENIOR RATE*CITIZENS 55YRS PLUS OR AARP ID\n1 QUEEN BED,MOBILITY ACC,COMMASSIST,ROLL SHWR,\nNSMK,CONTINENTAL BREAKFAST"
            }
          },
          "guests": {
            "adults": 1
          },
          "price": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "base": "242.10",
            "total": "281.31",
            "variations": {
              "average": {
                "base": "242.10"
              },
              "changes": [
                {
                  "startDate": "2020-09-13",
                  "endDate": "2020-09-14",
                  "base": "242.10"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "policies": {
            "paymentType": "guarantee",
            "cancellation": {
              "deadline": "2020-09-11T09:30:00+05:30"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "self": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=BWNYC133"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "links": {
      "next": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=NYC&page[offset]=BF2MJFOB9ASN_100"
    }
  }
}}
```

When i pass the above value to the angular controller its becomes empty ,My Angular code

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
                var hexa = response.data;
                alert(hexa);
                console.log(hexa);
        

}
```

Comment: Could you post more code in html, my friend? Maybe everybody can help you better.

Comment: Bro all i need is to get the json values in the alert box..

Comment: Why are you deserializing twice? It seems that you are deserializing an already deserialized object, unless I'm missing something.

myJsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).ToString();
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonResponse);
parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);